# Rspec throws invalid option for --bisect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I wanted to use `--bisect` option (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/bisect) with my tests, but it didn't work.

```
$ rspec --bisect=verbose
invalid option: --bisect=verbose

$ rspec --bisect
invalid option: --bisect

$ rspec --seed 1234 --bisect
invalid option: --bisect
```

Could you please help me to figure out why it is not working?

Comment: and what version of rspec are you using?

Comment: @sevenseacat rspec version is 3.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bisect` option was only added to RSpec in 3.3, as seen in the changelog here:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.3.0/Changelog.md

> Add --bisect CLI option, which will repeatedly run your suite in order to isolate the failures to the smallest reproducible case. (Myron Marston, #1917)